# Cordova: copying file from & to specific dir

Tags: cordova

I m using `cordova` to copy index.html file from application `asset/www/` folder to any other folder so user can acess.

The code is shown below:

```
function copy(currDir, srcEntry, destDir) {   
  currDir.getFile(srcEntry, {}, function(fileEntry) {
    currDir.getDirectory(destDir, {}, function(dirEntry) {
      fileEntry.copyTo(dirEntry);
    }, errorHandler);   
  }, errorHandler); 
}
copy('how_to_specify_application_root_here', 'index.html',
    fileSystem.root+'Documents/');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use version `1.2.0` of the `file` plugin, which gives you access to the application directory. You'll need to resolve it to get a directory entry:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory, success, fail);
```

You'll have to modify `copy` somewhat to support this, but that should get you started.